# Pass tab li rel to change image src

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs, dynamic-linking

This one should be generally easy, but I am getting hung up.  I am trying to change an image src based on a tab on the page that is selected.  I was thinking hide show, but would rather write something more precise.  Code:

```
<img id="change_img" src="img/Change_Me.jpg" alt="" />

<ul class="tabs">
    <li rel="tab1">Tab1</li>
    <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
    <li rel="tab3">Tab 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
        <h2>Tab 1</h2>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
   <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
        <h2>Tab 2</h2>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  ...... etc.....
```

So when someone clicks on the li tab1 the rel gets past to src on the image above. So
    `<img id="change_img" src="img/tab1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img id="change_img" src="img/tab2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img id="change_img" src="img/tab3.jpg" alt="" />`
etc....  The image will always be a .jpg and be in the img folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .**[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to get `rel` value,

```
$('.tabs li').click(function(){
    $('#change_img').attr('src','img/'+$(this).attr("rel")+'.jpg');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QA6Mn/1/)**

Comment: Works better than rubbing to rabbit's feet together :]

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.tabs > li').click(function() {
    var thisTab = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('img#change_img').attr('src', 'img/'+thisTab+'.jpg');
  });
});
```

This snippet grabs the rel attribute of the list item that was clicked (which you already use for the tabs) and then adds it to the image source.